# Question on differential linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

**Question**: why in below example(see below) $I$ is open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ containing $0$? What happens when we take any other subinterval of $\mathbb{R}$ which does not contains $0$ ?

While solving examples on linear transformations, I came to **example** : " let $I$ be an open interval of $\mathbb{R}$ containing $0$. Let $D:C^1(I)→C^0(I)$ be differential mapping $D(f)=f'(x)$ then $D$ is linear transformation and $D$ is not injective but $D$ is surjective.

I have solved example completely but I am curious to know, why $I$ is open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ containing $0$? What happens when we take any other subinterval of $\mathbb{R}$ which does not contains $0$ ? I think $D$ still remains linear transformation and with same properties? Please help me

Comment: It is not needed to get linearity. It looks like that is part of an exercise with further parts. Maybe in those they are going to look at the subspace of functions that vanish at $0$ and define an inverse.

Comment: @user647486 Why it is not linear? If I choose $I=(1,2)$?

Comment: What I said is not that it is not linear. I said that the condition $0\in I$ is not needed to prove that it is linear.

Comment: @user647486 Is then the properties like $D$ is not injective and $D$ is surjective still holds or they changes if I change $I$?

Comment: Didn't you say you solved this exercise? Did your proof of non-injectivity or of surjectivity require $0$ to be in the interval? The non-injectivity of $D$ is almost trivial, and the surjectivity is a consequence of a very famous theorem. Neither one requires $0$. So we can't tell you why the author of your book chose to include it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair sir thank you so much for the reply. Yes $D$ is not injective as kernel of $D$ is non trivial. This does not require presence of $0$ in $I$. Sir you said surjectivity follows from theorem." Which theorem?" According to hint given I consider $J: C^0→C^1$ such that $$J(f(x))=\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$$ then $DJ(f)=D(J(f))=f$ for all $x\in I$ this shows that, for each $f\in C^0(I)$ there exists $J(f)\in C^1(I)$ such that $D(J(f))=f$ hence $D$ is surjective. Is presence $0$ in lower limit of integral symbol forces author to take subinterval of $\mathbb{R}$ containing $0$?

Comment: The fundamental theorem of calculus, which is what you used to say that D(J(f)) = f. The presence of $0$ in $I$ is not necessary. Simply pick any $a$ in $I$, and $\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$ is an antiderivative of $f$.

Comment: Sir thank you so ...much